# how to fix "npm ERR! Missing script:"

Tags: node.js, json, npm, sass

I wrote the script "style", but for some reason does not want to execute it.
Using the npm run command, you can just execute the script "test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
My package.json is below, as well as the full error message when I run a command:

```
  {
  "name": "plants",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "style": "sass sass/style.scss sass/style.css",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

here I am trying to run a sktipt:

```
npm run style
npm ERR! Missing script: "style"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\GRAFIK548\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-12-28T06_18_17_306Z-debug-0.log
```

and here I look at what scripts can be run:

```
$ npm run
Lifecycle scripts included in plants@1.0.0:
  test
    echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1
```

in general, I'm trying to connect sass via json

thank you very much for any answer!!

Comment: use npm i sass then run the project

Comment: Sujith Kumar, I still have only "test" script after comand npm run

Answer (score 0):

### NPM err missing script fix

---

I used to get this error a lot on my old computer. The easiest fix I found that worked was to just

> **Try to use the absolute path of the file in your JSON.**